# JHipster friltering in CRUDs pages

Tags: filter, code-generation, jhipster, crud

i'm ramping up in JHipster, and i'm trying this approach: use the generated pages and code to earn development time.

I have a requirement to filter entities/tables content for certain fields/column within CRUDs. Another requirement is not to use Elasticsearch.

My idea is to add filtering fields to those pages and use the generated classes *entity*Criteria.java to filter data.

I don't know how to map search criterion to that class, from the *entity*.component.ts script.

I can add criteria programatically, but i think is good idea to modify only that and, as i allready says, earn a lot of development time.

Can anyone orient me on the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved adding the filter fields to the controller and the page. Also add an initialization for each field in the constructor.

The filter criteria is added in the loadAll method.

Just like that.